# Access surface behind a view

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Is it possible to access the surface that a view is based on? The only function I found was takeSurface, but that function will then prevent any further updates to the view.

I want to access the surface and feed it into the MediaCodec where I can create a video. I would want to grab a frame from the surface at a regular time interval which is set by the frames per second I want to achieve.

Comment: Access to the underlying surface is provided via the SurfaceHolder interface, which can be retrieved by calling getHolder(). 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView


Check LineageOS Screen Recorder, this might give you some hints.

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Recorder/blob/lineage-17.1/app/src/main/java/org/lineageos/recorder/screen/ScreencastService.java#L267

Comment: @RajatGupta No, I'm not using a SurfaceView. I want to acess the surface for any view.